# Trying to implement multiple values to a state using React Hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
const [tag, setTag] = useState([]);
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");


const dataSource = [
{ id: 1, name: "Sad af" },
{ id: 2, name: "Sad boy" },
{ id: 3, name: "idk" },
{ id: 4, name: "Sad" },
{ id: 5, name: "Javascript" },
{ id: 6, name: "Kode" } ]



            <View style={styles.row}>
              {dataSource.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={{
                      margin: 5,
                      flexWrap: "wrap",
                    }}
                  >
                    <Chip
                      key={item}
                      height={35}
                      textStyle={
                        selectedItem === item.name
                          ? styles.pressChipText
                          : styles.chipText
                      }
                      style={
                        selectedItem === item.name
                          ? styles.pressChip
                          : styles.chip
                      }
                      onPress={() => {
                        setSelectedItem(item.name), setTag(item.name);
                      }}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </Chip>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
```

So im'm trying add more values to the tag state, so the user can add more values to the tag state. Currently the code allows only one value to get stored in the tag. I want to give the option to add one or more values to the tag state. Do you guys have any clever ideas? I'm using react-paper-chips to visual the design.

Comment: You're trying to implement a kind of multi select list?

Comment: Yeah that's about right.

Comment: You can store in your state an array of selected items and each time an item is pressed you can push that item into that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's quite simple**

Just make this change `setTag([...tag, item.name]` *`[it's called spread syntax]`*

```
  onPress={() => {
       setSelectedItem(item.name), setTag([...tag, item.name]);
 }}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked too! But what i do if i want to remove the value after clicking it? E.g. i click on a value, and right after that i want to remove it from the state tag. Because now if i click on a value, it just getting multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you initialize the `tag` as an array, but set it to a particular value. Instead of `setTag(item.name)` add a value to an array, like so:

```
const addTag = (name) => {
    const newTag = [...tag];
    newTag.push(name);
    setTag(newTag);
}
```

and call it: `addTag(item.name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make Tag an array of objects instead of names, like this `{name: "selectedItem"}`
So,
you could do

```
   onPress={() => setTag(previousState=>([...previousState, {[item.name]: item.name}]))}
```

previousState let you keep track of the other input value you put inside the tag state so you will not overwrite them, and can keep collecting the newState.